# C# - Casting an object to an interface

Tags: c#, .net, class, interface, casting

Suppose we have an interface:

```
interface ICustomShape
{
}
```

and we have a class that inherits from the Shape class, and implements the interface:

```
public class CustomIsocelesTriangle : Shape, ICustomShape
{

}
```

How would I go about casting a CustomIsocelesTriangle to a ICustomShape object, for use on an "interface level?"

```
ICustomShape x = (ICustomShape)canvas.Children[0]; //Gives runtime error: Unable to cast object of type 'program_4.CustomIsocelesTriangle' to type 'program_4.ICustomShape'.
```

Comment: What's the type of `canvas.Children[0]` in the debugger? You shouldn't even need a cast if it's `CustomIsocelesTriangle` - if it implements `ICustomShape` it should be accepted as such. My guess is that you're looking at the wrong type.

Comment: canvas.Children[0] is of type CustomIsocelesTriangle. The strange thing is, it works when I use the built-in geometry for an Ellipse, but for any objects that I defined my own path geometry, it gives this error (although, the drawing of the shapes/etc. everything works fine).

Comment: (I've tried edit post to name interface more standard `ICustomShape`, but it would change runtime error message... Please consider following default C# naming guidelines for public code - i.e. name interfaces like `ISomeInterface`)

Comment: Is your interface `CustomShape` or `ICustomShape`? And do you have a class `CustomShape` in the second case? Your code is confusing because of the bad edits.

Comment: Is the error message still accurate after your edits?

Comment: Massively updated my post with the implementation. Please look it over again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure that:

1. `canvas.Children[0]` returns a `CustomIsocelesTriangle`.
   Use the debugger to verify, or print the type to the console:

   ```
   var shape = canvas.Children[0];
   Console.WriteLine(shape.GetType());
   // Should print "program_4.CustomIsocelesTriangle"
   ```
2. You're casting to `ICustomShape` (not `CustomShape`).
3. `CustomIsocelesTriangle` implements `ICustomShape`.
   Try this to verify (it should compile):

   ```
   ICustomShape shape = new CustomIsocelesTriangle(/* Fake arguments */);
   ```

Then perhaps:

- you have `CustomIsocelesTriangle` in a different project or assembly, and you forgot to save and rebuild it after you made it implement `ICustomShape`;
- or, you reference an older version of the assembly;
- or, you have two interfaces named `ICustomShape` or two classes `CustomIsocelesTriangle` (perhaps in different namespaces), and you (or the compiler) got them mixed up.

Comment: Sorry -- fixed my notation. The CustomShape is the ICustomShape, I just didn't have it named correctly. canvas.Children[0] is of type CustomIsocelesTriangle

Comment: @Shaku In your post, even after all the edits, you still refer to `CustomShape` (without the `I`) in the last line. Are you sure you didn't make the same typo in your code?

Comment: @Shaku Your error (which I suppose you copy-and-pasted) also mentions just `CustomShape`.

Comment: Fixed. Yes, it was copy+pasted without the "I" since I had it named incorrectly.

Comment: @Shaku I changed my post.

Comment: Massively updated my post with the implementation. Please look it over again.